# how to authenticate users who maually enter the url in browser using the token based authentication?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, jwt, restful-authentication

I am authenticating users from my angular js web app using the authorization headers by passing the jwt token.I found that Auth-interceptor intercepts only the http requests made from that page.Now suppose 'mysite.com/page' requires authentication and the user enters it manually in other tab,how could I check that he is authenticated.I found that no headers are being passed through the request,and the user is found "Not Logged in" even though he is logged in in the other tab.

Comment: Use `$http` to make request and check auth.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you currently store the jwt token between each request?
You could store it in localStorage.

Then in the run() function of your auth module, you can check if there's a jwt token available in the local storage. If so you can use it.

Localstorage is available for all windows of the same domain. If the user opens your site in another window, the jwt token in localstorage will be found.

Comment: okay how can I find whether user has a local storage from the server side.can you please show me any reference.this is the first time I am using tokens

Comment: You don't do this from server side. You store the token in your local storage.
1. you authenticate to the server
2. server sends you a jwt token
3. you store it in localstorage. Since it's in local storage, it's available accross windows
4. on each request you add this token

Comment: can I have some reference regarding this